# regex difference with php whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I can't get this regex to work with PHP specifically the whitespace in the middle, the value or unit match group individually will match.

regex:

```
/(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)(\p{Z}|\s)(?<unit>(meters|mm))/
```

string to parse:

```
Cord Length:1.52 meters
```

try on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ it doesn't match.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bV7

try on https://regex101.com/ it works fine

EDIT: still doesn't seem to be working on phpliveregex.com for me

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bV7

EDIT2: I have edited the string to parse.

Comment: it works well on phpliveregex too: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bV5

Comment: phpliveregex worked fine for me, but you do have to remove the delimeters (it adds them on, so by leaving them you get duplicates). This is something that regex101 does automatically on paste.

Comment: still doesn't seem to be working for me, please see edit and link in OP

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the above comments, I would modify your regular expression as follows:

```
(?<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\h+(?<unit>(?:meters|mm))
```

Comment: still doesn't seem to be working for me, please see edit and link in OP

Comment: Click my link in the original post. It has a different character code for the space

Comment: it doesn't work you've changed the whitespace character.

Comment: Then use `/(?<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\pZ+(?<unit>(?:meters|mm))/iu`